# Regular Expression in Nodepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am stuck in creating a regular expression in Notepad++ which should find out the following pattern of line

```
/ic.nsf/0/44D01B63A7899E8F45258184002BCD05/$FILE/about.gif
```

where

```
44D01B63A7899E8F45258184002BCD05
```

is a randomly generated id and would be unique across the document, although the pattern of it is same as above. And want to replace it with a single i.e.

```
images
```

I have tried following expressions in find box

```
\/[a-z]\.\/[0-9].\/[0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z]\/\$[A-Z]
```

and

```
/ic.nsf/0/?/$FILE
```

and

```
\/ic.nsf\/0\/[a-z]\/\$FILE
```

But it doesn't find anything. Can anybody help??

Comment: What about this ? `ic\.nsf\/\w+\/[A-Z0-9]*\/(.*?)\/(.*?\.(?:gif|png|jpg))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find what:**

```
\/ic\.nsf\/\d+\/[0-9A-F]+\/\$FILE
```

**Replace with:**

```
images
```

Produces:

```
images/about.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

search after

```
(/ic.nsf/0/)[0-9A-Z]+(/\$FILE/about.gif)
```

and replace with

```
$1images$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression for search:

```
(\/ic\.nsf\/0\/)([^//]+)
```

And for replace use `\1` as a link for first part

```
\1images
```

[image]